# How to print the number of nodes of a certain type referencing to content

Tags: 7, views

Using Drupal 7 and the latest [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) modules.
I have 3 content types:
- Destination
- Museum
- Restaurant

Museum and Restaurant both reference Destination via field_destination through Entity Reference. What I'm trying to do is to pull on each Destination page the number of each (Museums and Restaurants) in a block.
Bear in mind that Destination doesn't directly reference to neither, it only gets referenced in the other 2 content types.
Managed so far to create 2 relationships, one depending on the other, to pull out a sort of 2 ways reference.
Once I can pull out information about one specific content type pointing to Destination, I can use aggregation and set it up. The problem is... I cannot differentiate.

Any suggestions on how to make the difference between the two when they both use the same reference field?

Comment: Hello and welcome. You tagged it (correctly) with Views. So what have you tried? We don't provide whole solutions developed from scratch here, and counting nodes with views was already talked about here, in similar context.

Comment: Created a view block printing fields. Added a contextual filter Content: NID - content ID from URL, validation criteria: content type Destination. This block is now printed only on Destination pages.

-1st field is NID - exclude from Display.
-1st relationship is Referencing Content via field_destination.
-2nd relationship - Referenced Content via field_destination, using the first relationship.

Now I can directly point to nodes relating to Destination using the second relationship.

What next? How can I differentiate between the 2 separate content types, Restaurant and Museum?

Comment: The thing is I can easily print the total number of nodes pointing to Destination. I just dont know how to differentiate.

Comment: @Catalin, I'm not entirely sure I follow, but could you just do two separate views? And filter each on a different content type?

Comment: Thanks, @Letharion. Separate views works, yes. Listing only specific content type nodes in each view, strip them naked as they are a list with no extra markup and publish the views as a list. Maybe even a view of views could do the trick.

Thought it would be possible with one view.